# Check only one checkbox and uncheck others using livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to check only one checkbox at a time and others uncheck, but when I want to check a new checkbox then the previous will uncheck, and so on.

my code in blade:

```
@foreach($addressEmployer as $address)
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 p-2 m-2 rounded" style="border: dashed #a1a1a1;">
                                <label for="check{{$address->id}}"></label>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2 mt-5">
                                        <input wire:model="addressSelected.{{$address->id}}"
                                               value="{{$address->id}}"
                                               class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                               id="check{{$address->id}}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-10">
                                        <p> {{$address->province->name}} - {{$address->city->name}}</p>
                                        <p> {{$address->address}}</p>
                                        <a wire:click="setAddress({{$address->id}})" class="float-end"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                           href="#editAddressModal"
                                           role="button">{{__('Edit')}}</a>
                                        <a wire:click="$emit('addressId',{{$address->id}})" class=" me-3 float-end"
                                           data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                           href="#deleteAddressModal"
                                           role="button">{{__('Delete')}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
```

I read the addresses from the database and display them with foreach and I want to select one of the displayed addresses.

**I am looking for the right solution to this issue. Thanks if you have a solution.**

Comment: This is how `radio` buttons works. Can't you use the radio buttons instead?

Comment: I tested the radio and it still does not work and when you select one and check the next, the previous one will not be uncheked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple options but want to limit selection to a single option, [radio buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) are your friend.

If the previously selected radio button is not de-selecting, it suggests you haven't grouped your radio button elements correctly using the `name` attribute.

Here is a simplified example to get you on the right path.

**Component**

```
class AddressComponent extends Component
{
    public $addresses = Address::all();

    public $selectedAddressId;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->addresses = Address::all();
        $this->selectedAddressId = 1;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.address-component-view');
    }
}
```

**Component view**

```
<div>
    @foreach ($addresses as $address)
        <div class="mt-1">
            <input type="radio" id="{{ $address->id }}" name="address" value="{{ $address->id }}" wire:model="selectedAddressId" />
            <label for="{{ $address->id }}">{{ $address->address }}</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    <h3>Selected Address ID: {{ $selectedAddressId }}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not shure why you're trying this with checkbox, instead of radiobutton. But maybe you can handle something like this

```
public $addressSelected = [];

protected $rules = [
  'addressSelected.id' => 'nullable'
];

public function updatingAddressSelected($value)
{
  $this->addressSelected = [];
}

// in blade add the wire:key directive to checkbox's root div
<div class="col-2 mt-5" wire:key="checkbox-id-{{ $address->id }}">
  <input wire:model="addressSelected.{{$address->id}}"
    value="{{$address->id}}"
    class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
    id="check{{$address->id}}"
    @if(in_array($address->id,$addressSelected)) checked @endif
  >
</div>
```